# Can't JSON Web Tokens be easily stolen?

Tags: cookies, jwt, cross-domain, xss

I'm reading about JWTs and I'm really confused by something which doesn't seem to be addressed:

What is stopping a malicious website from just including

```
localStorage.get ('secretjwt')
```

in their code and stealing your tokens?

If you don't store it as a cookie then anyone can access it! And if it stored as a cookie, then why not just use cookies full-on?

Answer (score 3):

Cookies and localStorage are protected by [same-origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) policy

> In computing, the same-origin policy is an important concept in the web application security model. Under the policy, **a web browser permits scripts contained in a first web page to access data in a second web page, but only if both web pages have the same origin.**

For example http://www.malicious.com or http://www.example.com can not access to storage in https://www.example.com

Additionaly the site should use SSL/TLS to encrypt the content and prevent the token from being stolen

Comment: Having said that, one single XSS can be used to obtain the token from localStorage (or sessionStorage or websql or anything similar), as opposed to an httpOnly cookie, where this would not be the case.